# ClickHouse Replication not working over secure channels: No interserver IO endpoint named

Tags: clickhouse

I am testing replication over secure channels following this article:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/sre/configuring-ssl/ 
But can’t make it working yet. When I insert data, the replication doesn’t work with error messages like under (from the replica node):

> 2023.03.20 16:51:00.757079 [ 32722 ] {}  mybd.mytable (b4a7593a-c2e1-4d2d-90ec-f8050c17a19a): auto DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::processQueueEntry(ReplicatedMergeTreeQueue::SelectedEntryPtr)::(anonymous class)::operator()(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr &) const: Code: 86. DB::HTTPException: Received error from remote server /?endpoint=DataPartsExchange%3A%2Fclickhouse%2Ftables%2F01%2Fmydb%2Fmytable%2Freplicas%2F02&part=20230320_66_71_1&client_protocol_version=7&compress=false. HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: Code: 221. DB::Exception: No interserver IO endpoint named DataPartsExchange:/clickhouse/tables/01/mydb/mytable/replicas/02. (NO_SUCH_INTERSERVER_IO_ENDPOINT), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

The secure channel ports (including secure inter_server 9010) are listening and the related features e.g., clickhouse-client and ZK 4lw, work fine over the secure channels.
I have 2 Clickhouse Keeper nodes (MY-232 and MY-233) with a 2 nodes cluster with which I had tested replications w/o secure channels. And it worked fine.
FYI, the error messages are from MY-232 when I insert data to MY-233. When I insert data to MY-232 instead, the replication doesn’t work either but the error messages from MY-233 are DNS related. I am debugging it too but not adding the information of it here for simplicity. If needed, I can add that info too.
I have checked/gone through this discussion: [Clickhouse Replication not happening 'DB::Exception: No interserver IO endpoint named'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851884/clickhouse-replication-not-happening-dbexception-no-interserver-io-endpoint)

Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Configurations, etc/hosts, table:

```
--- from MY-232
<interserver_https_port>9010</interserver_https_port>
<interserver_http_host>10.5.106.232</interserver_http_host>   <!— I have tried “MY-232.ch_test.local” —>

<zookeeper>
    <node>
        <host>MY-232.ch_test.local</host>
        <port>9281</port>
        <secure>1</secure>
    </node>
    <node>
        <host>MY-233.ch_test.local</host>
        <port>9281</port>
        <secure>1</secure>
    </node>
</zookeeper>

<keeper_server>
    <tcp_port>9281</tcp_port>
    <server_id>1</server_id>
    <log_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/log</log_storage_path>
    <snapshot_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/snapshots</snapshot_storage_path>

    <coordination_settings>
        <operation_timeout_ms>10000</operation_timeout_ms>
        <session_timeout_ms>30000</session_timeout_ms>
        <raft_logs_level>trace</raft_logs_level>
    </coordination_settings>

    <raft_configuration>
        <server>
            <id>1</id>
            <hostname>MY-232.ch_test.local</hostname>
            <port>9444</port>
            <secure>1</secure>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>2</id>
            <hostname>MY-233.ch_test.local</hostname>
            <port>9444</port>
            <secure>1</secure>
        </server>
    </raft_configuration>
</keeper_server>

<remote_servers>
    <cluster_1s_2r>
        <shard>
            <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
            <replica>
                <host>MY-232.ch_test.local</host>
                <port>9440</port>
                <user>default</user>
                <password></password>
                <secure>1</secure>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>MY-233.ch_test.local</host>
                <port>9440</port>
                <user>default</user>
                <password></password>
                <secure>1</secure>
            </replica>
        </shard>
    </cluster_1s_2r>
</remote_servers>

<macros>
    <shard>01</shard>
    <replica>01</replica>
</macros>

— MY-233
<interserver_https_port>9010</interserver_https_port>
<interserver_http_host>10.5.106.233</interserver_http_host>
<keeper_server>
    <tcp_port_secure>9281</tcp_port_secure>
    <server_id>2</server_id>

<macros>
    <shard>01</shard>
    <replica>02</replica>
</macros>

--- /etc/hosts
10.5.106.232 MY-232.ch_test.local
10.5.106.233 MY-233.ch_test.local

— table —
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable ON CLUSTER cluster_1s_2r
(
    `field1` String,
     …..
    `fieldX` Int32
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/mydb/mytable’, '{replica}')
```

Comment: > are DNS related. Try to add both servernames into /etc/hosts

Comment: Thanks Denny, however, I already have ones in /etc/hosts like this:

    10.5.106.232 MY-232.ch_test.local
    10.5.106.233 MY-233.ch_test.local

Please let me know if you meant something else. 
Meantime, I will try some related to DNS.

Comment: Please find the better format of /etc/hosts contents from my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue: interserver_http_host. Should use interserver_https_host instead.
I am glad that this was not an SSL specific issue.

Thanks Denny for the information.
DNS issue (another issue) was because of that one node had a hostname problem.